# Attaching event in loop

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

What am doing is attaching event on a class using a loop and index values are being used in the event handler code. Here is my code:

```
var classElements=document.getElementsByClassName("a");
for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    classElements[i].onClick=function(){
       alert("Clicked button : "+i);
    }
}
```

Whenever I click any of the buttons, it alerts:

> Clicked Button : 4

What could be the problem?

Comment: You're telling it to alert `i`, but you're constantly changing `i`, ultimately setting it to 4.

Comment: Good reading: [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: what am I supposed to do then if I want it to alert i?

Comment: @Sourabh Just wait, the answers are coming. This may be a pivotal point in your life as a JavaScript programmer ;)

Comment: FYI: `onClick` should be `onclick`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript closes over the object and evaluates it later when it is called.  At the time it is called, `i` is 4.

I think you want something like:

```
var classElements=document.getElementsByClassName("a");
for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    classElements[i].onClick=function(j) { 
       return function(){
          alert("Clicked button : "+j);
       };
    }(i);
}
```

EDIT: shown with named functions to make the code more clear

```
var classElements=document.getElementsByClassName("a");
for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    var makeFn = function(j) { 
       return function(){
          alert("Clicked button : "+j);
       };
    };
    classElements[i].onClick = makeFn(i);
}
```

Comment: am not sure but I think when you pass an argument while attaching event like this, javascript pass an event object and not the variable we want to pas.

Comment: I pass an argument to a function that returns a function.  The returned function is the one that is attached.

Comment: if it were me, I'd wrap `function(j)` with some outer parens.  There can be some ambiguity about how/when you can autoexecute a function like that, and outer parens make it explicit.

Comment: see when you call a function like e.onclick=function(eve){........}, you are actually attaching a function to the onclick event of e right?, I think eve is the event object not the variable, sorry am still not getting your answer.

Comment: @Sourabh: `function(j) {...` is being invoked immediately, and the `return function(){...` is assigned as the handler. It becomes more  clear if you use a named function instead of an inline anonymous function. Perhaps Lou will update with that solution.

Comment: You beat me by 5 secs and your answer was still more complete :)

Answer (score 2):

You need a closure in order to capture the changes of `i`.  As Lou stated this is due to post evaluation.

```
var classElements=document.getElementsByClassName("a");
for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
    classElements[i].onclick = (function(i){
          return function(){ alert("Clicked button : " + i) }; 
       })(i);
```