# Javascript get title value from <li>

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

In general: What I want is to have PHP output an unordered list with books. When the user clicks on one of the titles, the details will be pulled from the DB and inserted into the page using AJAX.

I can't seem to figure out how to pull the title value from the < li > using javascript, so I can pass that to AJAX.

(To simplify the example code, I left out the AJAX part and am using an alert instead.)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function()
{

      var shelve = document.getElementById( 'books' );
      var books = shelve.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
      for( var i=0; i < books.length; i++ ){
         books[i].onclick = function(){
        alert(books[i].title); //I know this doesn't work
         };
      }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="txtHint"><b>Book info will be listed here using AJAX.</b></div>

<?php show_allBooks(); ?>

</body>
</html>

<?php

function show_allBooks(){

    db_connect();
    $query = "Select * from tblBooks order by title";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    echo "<ul id='books'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<li title='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['title'] . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    db_close();
}
?>
```

I tried fooling around with variations of the following code, but this did not seem to work either.

```
books[i].getAttribute("title")
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [attaching event in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389021/attaching-event-in-loop)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Did google a lot before posting though.

Comment: No problem. This is one of the problems you have to know what it is about in order to be able to search for it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time your `onclick` handler gets called, `i` has been incremented to `books.length`.  Instead, you can reference `this` to get the element.

```
var shelve = document.getElementById('books');
var books = shelve.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    books[i].onclick = function () {
        alert(this.title); 
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/cPMAU/

However, if you *do* need to know the value of `i` in the click handler, you can do it by creating your handler in a factory, that is a function that returns a function:

```
function createBookHandler(books, i) {
    return function() {
        alert(books[i].title);
    };
}
var shelve = document.getElementById('books');
var books = shelve.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    books[i].onclick = createBookHandler(books, i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/cPMAU/1/

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple and that I did not try to do this. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
books.item(i)
```

Then it depends how title is stored in the list. If its

```
<li title="">
```

then
    books.item(i).getAttribute("title")

But the closure related answer is probably more important.